# Extract values from Ruby data hash and concatenate values into single continuous String

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am working on a Ruby on Rails program currently and need a bit of help figuring out a method to take in a nested hash, extract the values, and concatenate those values together into a single String.

An example hash would be:

```
h={a:"da",b:{c:"test",e:{f:"bird"}},d:"duck"}
```

I would like the input to appear as such:

```
"datestbirdduck"
```

Would anyone be able to help with a metohod that can do this. I've had some trouble finding anything that works for a nested hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your input (`h`) is a hash that can contain hashes in its values, you can implement the method to extract the strings from the values using recursion:

```
input = {a: "da", b: {c:"test", e: {f: "bird"}}, d:"duck"}

def extract_values_from_hash(input)
  return input unless input.is_a?(Hash)

  input.flat_map { |_, v| extract_values_from_hash(v) }
end

extract_values_from_hash(input).join
# datestbirdduck
```

What it does is to receive the hash (`input`) from which extract the values adding a guard clause - as the base case, which returns the argument the method was called with if it's a hash object, otherwise it flattens and map the object invoking the method itself. This way you extract every value from the initial method argument.

Notice this extracts anything that's in the input that's not directly a hash, if you happen to have an object like this:

```
{a: "da", b: {c:"test", e: {f: "bird"}}, d:"duck", g: 1, h: [{i: "hola"}, {j: "chao"}]}
```

The result would be:

```
"datestbirdduck1{:i=>\"hola\"}{:j=>\"chao\"}"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Love the solution. I keep getting an error in the Rails console saying the Stack level is too deep for some reason though. Have you ever seen that?

Comment: Yes, it's maybe because it doesn't find a way to get out of the loop. Are you using exactly the same input you added in your question?

Comment: @KortneyStinson you get that kind of error when there are too many recursive calls. Maybe your hash is nested _very_ deeply. Could also be a cycle within the hash, e.g. something like `h = {}; h[:a] = h`

Comment: @Sebastian I did use exactly the same input. It randomly stopped after I reloaded the rails console. Hmmm, it's working perfectly now! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Stefan yeah I think that may have been an issue, but I reloaded the console and it started working perfectly. I'm going to try it with a larger hash that I'll actually be using